# DB2 Table with CAST or SUBSTR of TIME as part of the Primary Key?

Tags: db2, primary-key

I am trying to create a table, which could be updated very often by different apps, but I only care about the last entry for each hour regardless of what updated it. With that in mind, I was thinking that using the HOUR(CURRENT TIME) would be part of the primary key (just a part - not the whole thing). This could be anything like the following (if they worked):

```
NON-working sample
create table foo (
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(10),
lastdate date not null with default, 
lasthour varchar(2) not null with default cast(hour(current time) as varchar(2))
);
```

or

if I create lastvalue as: lastvalue time not null with default

```
create unique index foo_inx on foo (col1, col2, lastdate, hour(lastvalue));
```

I hope that's a reasonably interesting problem. :-)

- Edit: The ddl does not work. I've added lastdate to the unique index.

Comment: Will you only keep last day values?

Comment: ...So if you tried to run this, did it work?  If it didn't, you could synthesize it by using a `DECIMAL(2, 0)` as the type (and some appropriate `CHECK` constraints), then inserting using a stored proc to derive the value as necessary.  @Lennart has a good point, though; if data sits in the table for more than 24 hours, you're toast - an hour isn't valid on it's own.  Date/time also gets... strange in a global context - there are timezones with non-integral offsets, for example.  Don't have enough info, but I'd start with storing the full timestamp, and use a view to derive this information.

Comment: Interesting perspective to use timestamps and filter with a view. On the one side - that's easy and obvious (that's a good thing). On the other side, I was concerned that since these sensors could possibly fire thousands of times per hour, I was concerned with storing garbage. I think what I'll try is storing the date and time columns, filter with a view and occasionally clean up with a "dedup" process off hours. Thx.